# Deleting a pointer from a vector using loops (not iterators)

Tags: c++, c++11, computer-science

I have a method that is passed an object, finds that object in a vector of pointers by matching its address in a loop, and needs to remove the matching item from the vector without deleting the item (i.e the item needs to still exist in memory). Currently, this is the method:

```
void remove(Soldier& soldier) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < armySize(); ++i) {
        if (army[i] == &soldier) {
            cout << army[i]->getName() << "is removed" << endl;
            army.erase(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `soldier` is the object that needs to be removed and `army` is a vector of `Soldier` pointers. The `if` statement works, meaning that the address of `soldier` and an item in the vector matches. The problem is that I get an error that says "no matching member function for call to 'erase'". How would I fix this without using iterators (no new, delete or begin method)?

Comment: Why don't you want to use iterators?

Comment: `army.begin() + i` is an iterator to the item you're trying to erase. Not sure why you're dead set against something so simple.

Comment: I can't use iterators because that's part of the spec

Answer (score 4):

You can swap element you are trying to erase with the last one and use [`std::vector::pop_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back):

```
 if( i != army.size() - 1 ) 
     std::swap( army[i], army.back() );
 army.pop_back();
```

in your case if you use pointers you may simply override:

```
army[i] = army.back();
army.pop_back();
```

This method would be more efficient than calling `std::vector::erase()` but order of elements would be affected.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the declaration of `std::vector::erase`, it is:

```
iterator erase( const_iterator pos );
```

As you can see, the argument is an interator. You're trying to pass an integer as the argument. As such, the overload resolution doesn't find an overload with the type of argument that you're passing. That is what the error *"no matching member function for call to 'erase'"* means.

There is no way of using `std::vector::erase` without using an iterator.

---

> How would I fix this without using iterators

You could overwrite the element to be removed with the last element, and then call `pop_back` to remove the duplicate. Both of those can be done without iterators.

If you want to keep the order like `erase` would, then overwrite the target element with the next one. Then overwrite the next one with the one after that, and so on until the end of the vector. Then `pop_back`. That said, I would recommend using iterators and `erase` instead. There is no need to complicate the program by arbitrarily disallowing the use of iterators.